# Got weird result when executing bash command "cd /usr/share/; ls *z "

Tags: ls

I know the meaning of `*` wildcard

But when I use Ubuntu 14.04 and type following command:

```
$ cd /usr/share/
$ ls *z
```

But why the part of the result is like this:

[image]
                **NOTE:** You can click the link above to get a larger version of it.

Some files do not end with `z`. Is that normal or did I miss something here?

Comment: What does it say with `echo *z`?

Comment: it'd be helpful if you could paste the output as /text/ instead of as an image - makes it easier to read/debug.

Comment: Second what @JeffSchaller said, but if I squint my eyes, it looks like the contents of `/usr/share/compiz`, which ends with `z`, so it seems normal...?

Comment: @Celada , http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/11.4/x86_64/compiz-0.9.2.1-5.5.x86_64.html shows the files listed, so /usr/share/compiz is indeed *z.

Comment: The problem comes from fact that if you order `ls` to list many directories it firstly prints their names and then content (files). However if `ls` list only one directory (as in this case) then only content is printed (without directory name), so sometimes you may be surprised if other behaviour is expected.

Comment: The `-d` option of `ls` is your friend.  If you type `ls -d *z` (or, better yet, `ls -ld *z`) you will see what the `*z` matches, rather than the *contents* of that thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try `ls -ld *z` , you will see a directory ending in z.
So, `ls *z` becomes `ls "One-Directory-Ending-With-z"` and so you get the contents of that Directory, which seems to have a lot of xml files.